# Enable root on current user in Docker

Tags: docker

given that $USERNAME is set to 'ros', I woiuld like to create a user called ros, with a home directory, home/ros, with sudo privs and no password.

```
RUN adduser --ingroup sudo --disabled-password --gecos "" --shell /bin/bash --home /home/$USERNAME $USERNAME
```

Does that not do it?

Comment: `sudo` tends to not work well in Docker, and it's usually unnecessary since both `docker run` and `docker exec` take a `-u` option that lets you specify another user.  You also usually wouldn't want to do admin-type actions in a container since any work you do by hand will get lost as soon as the container gets deleted; building a custom image is usually better and more reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Docker is simple, it just runs the commands you give it against the image base you start with. That one line is making a bunch of assumptions that may or may not be true:

1. `adduser` is installed
2. `sudo` is installed
3. `/etc/sudoers` is configured to allow root permissions for users in the `sudo` group
4. `/bin/bash` is installed
5. You've already created `/home`
6. You've already created `/home/$USERNAME`

If all those assumptions are true before that `RUN` line, then it may work, but of course, there may be another assumption I'm overlooking.